# How does Leaflet layer ordering work with CartoDB layers?

Tags: leaflet, layers, carto, z-index

All,

I'm trying to figure out how Leaflet layer ordering works when you have layers coming from CartoDB. I have a map with 1 polygon layer (cartodb), 3 point layers (cartodb), 1 basemap layer (mapbox) (and in the future hope to add tabletopJS or another google spreadsheet conduit...)

The [Leaflet Layers example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html) seems straight forward when using cloudmade layer URL's that end in the {z}/{x}/{y}.png format, which will work for Mapbox as well.

However, I can't see how to get the {z}/{x}/{y}.png format for a CartoDB layer, and wonder if the same interactivity will be supported (custom infowindows, etc.)

So far I have tried this to no avail:

```
function layersMap() {
    var voices = cartodb.createVis('map', 'http://opendetroit.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/08140c18-8a05-11e3-ae46-0e49973114de/viz.json');
        devPoints = cartodb.createLayer('map', 'http://opendetroit.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/62a64dd6-4d7d-11e3-b48c-db82dabd16be/viz.json'); 
    var points = L.layerGroup([voices, devPoints]);
    var map = new L.map('map', {
    center : [42.339926, -83.04137],
    zoom : 13,
    layers: [points]
    });

}
```

The problem with this attempt, however, is the 2nd layer doesn't draw, and there is actually two zoom controls displaying.

This is as close a solution as I can find by going through as much info on GIS.SE, Leaflet docs, CartoDB docs, etc.

So it seems I might be on the right track by getting 1 CartoDB layer to display...but not sure where to go from here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution:

```
var map = new L.map('map', {
center : [42.339926, -83.04137],
zoom : 13
});
L.tileLayer('http://tile.stamen.com/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: 'Stamen'
    }).addTo(map);

var voices = cartodb.createLayer(map, 'http://opendetroit.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/08140c18-8a05-11e3-ae46-0e49973114de/viz.json').addTo(map);
    devPoints = cartodb.createLayer(map, 'http://opendetroit.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/62a64dd6-4d7d-11e3-b48c-db82dabd16be/viz.json').addTo(map);
```

http://codepen.io/milafrerichs/pen/VYOgpN

You can even create LayerGroups. Don't add the layer to the map and add a `.on`

```
cartodb.createLayer(map, 'viz.json')
     .on('done', function(layer) {
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, example didn't worked in codepen, but it worked in a html file that I made. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

neither createLayer or createVis return a leaflet layer, the right way would be

```
 var map = new L.map('map', {
    center : [42.339926, -83.04137],
    zoom : 13

 });

// add here your mapbox layer

createLayer(map,vizjson_url).addTo(map).done(function(layer) {
  layer.setZIndex(1);
})
createLayer(map,vizjson_url2).addTo(map).done(function(layer) {
  layer.setZIndex(2);
})
```

Comment: thank you @javisantana... does this mean layer groups are out of the question?

Comment: You can do with it a leaflet layergroup also, but you need to wait both done are called. ``layer`` param in a leaflet tiledlayer object

Comment: is there an example of that anywhere?

Comment: just tried the example above but nothing loads...

Comment: @mapBaker could you share the example to see what is happening?

Comment: @javisantana as of carto JS 3.15, setZIndex doesn't seem to exist any more.