# CartoDB layer not showing up on over mapbox layer but legend is

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, html, jquery

Currently, the legend is only displaying but not the layer.

NOTE: I am trying to run the web map on a bootstrap modal, hence you will see: `$('#webmap-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function()` in the code I am posting.

With that being said, here is the code:

```js
var map;

$('#webmap-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiaXRzbXNkIiwiYSI6ImNpaGU1cGRycDBqb290dGx6aGFkcDd4ODMifQ.21JHrd2HAFyrCxa4XLF7rQ';
  map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.light', {
    minZoom: 3
  }).setView([60.751723, -105.907315], 3);

  L.control.scale().addTo(map);

  L.tileLayer('', {
    attribution: 'Created by <a href="">Kam</a>',
  }).addTo(map);

  var cdb_layer = cartodb.createLayer(map, 'https://itsmsd.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/00873ec2-94ab-11e5-8e1b-0e3ff518bd15/viz.json')
    .addTo(map);

  L.control.layers({
    'Grey Canvas': L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.light').addTo(map),
    'Street Canvas': L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.streets'),
    'Emerald Canvas': L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.outdoors'),
    'Dark Canvas': L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.dark'),
    'Simple Canvas': L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.streets-basic'),
  }).addTo(map);
});
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
  <script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/cartodb.js"></script>
  <link rel="http://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
  <style>
    #map {
      height: 100%;
      margin-top: 4%;
    }
    .leaflet-control-layers label {
      text-align: left;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map" style="width:900px; height:570px"></div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".letter").click(function(e) {
        $(".letter").parent().removeClass('current');
        $(this).parent().addClass('current');
        var letter = $(this).html().trim();
        $(".submenuDiv").hide();
        x = e.clientX - 10;
        pos = $(this).position();
        y = pos.top + 30;
        $("#div" + letter).css({
          left: x,
          top: y,
          position: 'absolute'
        });
        $("#div" + letter).show();
      });
    });
  </script>
  <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.1/mapbox.standalone.js'></script>
  <script src="https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.uncompressed.js"></script>
</body>
```

Also, if it helps, I can zip the files and provide a downloadable link to.

Comment: Cross-posting on multiple stackexchange sites is discouraged.
See this: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4067/cross-posting-duplicate-questions-to-different-communities

Answer (score 1):

(duplicate of [CartoDB layer not showing up on over mapbox layer but legend is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973230/cartodb-layer-not-showing-up-on-over-mapbox-layer-but-legend-is) on Stack Overflow)

Answer copied below.

---

There seem to be several mistakes here.

First of all, you would facilitate your own debugging by testing each individual functionality **separately** (bootstrap, cartodb…).

You duplicate several libraries includes: Leaflet CSS and JS and jQuery (not sure about the version) are **already included** in CartoDB. You even include **twice** CartoDB! This is calling for unpredictable results.

Next, you initially add a `mapbox.light` tileLayer, then your CartoDB layer, then again `mapbox.light` (in the Layers Control definition). So your CartoDB layer is already hidden. *That is very probably the reason why you see the attribution but not the layer on map.*

If you want your CartoDB layer to be always shown on top of any base layer that may be selected through the Layers Control, you would set it as a Layers Control **overlay** so that it is always added on top of the base layers (provided that the user keeps it selected in the Layers Control).

Note that you need to use the `on('done', function (layer) { /* add to Layers Control overlays */ })` callback to do so. See [How does one use leaflet layergroups with CartoDB layers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92520/how-does-one-use-leaflet-layergroups-with-cartodb-layers)

```js
var layersControl = L.control.layers({
    'Grey Canvas': L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.light').addTo(map),
    'Street Canvas': L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.streets'),
    'Emerald Canvas': L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.outdoors'),
    'Dark Canvas': L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.dark'),
    'Simple Canvas': L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.streets-basic')
}).addTo(map);

var cdb_layer = cartodb.createLayer(map, 'https://itsmsd.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/00873ec2-94ab-11e5-8e1b-0e3ff518bd15/viz.json')
    .addTo(map).on('done', function (layer) {
    layersControl.addOverlay(layer, 'CartoDB');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zfLgujhv/1/