# The ordering of layers with CartoDB/Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, carto, carto-js

Just want to get a bit of clarity about this query from before:

[Layer order in CartoDB](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88855/how-does-leaflet-layer-ordering-work-with-cartodb-layers)

I have a map with a Basemap and I want to draw points between features based on layer featureclicks, The good news is I've got that far.

However i'd like my newly created layer to sit between the marker layer and the tile layer. Is this even possible?

Heres a link to my code on [github](https://github.com/OmarSarhan/UK-PLacenames-Filter/blob/master/CartoDB.html)

Comment: could you clarify a little bit the question: name the layers and the order you want to achieve. Some code extracts would be also good. thanks

Comment: Hi The code can be found [here](https://github.com/OmarSarhan/UK-PLacenames-Filter/blob/master/CartoDB.html)
I'd like the polyline created on lines 81-86  to sit under the layer with the markers and above the tilelayer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code syntax is incorrect. Please, verify it and check blocks.

I'm attaching a snapshot about it (because of that this is an answer, and not a comment)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the blocks, any ideas on solving the actual problem?